# KeyError: date value

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I got a csv file with the following columns:
Province/State  Country/Region  Lat     Long    1/22/20     1/23/20 ...

This is the dataframe:

```
Country/Region  1/22/20     1/23/20     1/24/20
Afghanistan     100         200          300
Albania         400         500           0
Algeria          20          30           70
```

I'm trying to get a function with inputs: csv-file and last date I want to filter.

Here I show the function I did:

```
def create_covid_pickle (csv_doc, date):
    csv_doc = pd.read_csv(csv_doc)
    # assign correct format to date
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date,"%m-%d-%y")
    date = date.strftime("%m/%d/%y")
        
    # delete columns I don't need
    csv_doc = csv_doc.loc[:, 'Country/Region': date]
    csv_doc = csv_doc.drop(columns = ['Lat', 'Long'])
    
    # to_dict
    #     csv_dictionary = csv_doc.to_dict()
    csv_dictionary = [{c: {'time': d.columns.tolist(), 'cases': d.values.tolist()[0]}} 
                      for c, d in csv_doc.set_index(['Country/Region']).groupby('Country/Region')]
      
    return csv_dictionary
```

I am getting 2 errors in  `csv_doc = csv_doc.loc[:, 'Country/Region': date]` The first, when using `.loc[]` and the second because of date `date`

The complete message of error shown is

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_slice_bound(self, label, side, kind)
   4844             try:
-> 4845                 return self._searchsorted_monotonic(label, side)
   4846             except ValueError:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in _searchsorted_monotonic(self, label, side)
   4805 
-> 4806         raise ValueError("index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing")
   4807 

ValueError: index must be monotonic increasing or decreasing

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-a84a2fe01741> in <module>
      1 # Test
----> 2 create_covid_pickle("data/time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv", "01-06-20")
      3 
      4 # Load and print some data
      5 # country_cases = pickle.load(open("primera_ola.pkl", "rb"))

<ipython-input-1-1c34e9c20811> in create_covid_pickle(csv_doc, date)
     29 
     30     # seleccionar columnas - crear funcion 1 indepte?
---> 31     csv_doc = csv_doc.loc[:, 'Country/Region': date]
     32 
     33 #     REVISAR FUNCION CON NUEVOS CAMBIOS DE LAS LINEAS ANTERIORES

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1760                 except (KeyError, IndexError, AttributeError):
   1761                     pass
-> 1762             return self._getitem_tuple(key)
   1763         else:
   1764             # we by definition only have the 0th axis

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_tuple(self, tup)
   1287                 continue
   1288 
-> 1289             retval = getattr(retval, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
   1290 
   1291         return retval

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _getitem_axis(self, key, axis)
   1910         if isinstance(key, slice):
   1911             self._validate_key(key, axis)
-> 1912             return self._get_slice_axis(key, axis=axis)
   1913         elif com.is_bool_indexer(key):
   1914             return self._getbool_axis(key, axis=axis)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py in _get_slice_axis(self, slice_obj, axis)
   1794 
   1795         labels = obj._get_axis(axis)
-> 1796         indexer = labels.slice_indexer(
   1797             slice_obj.start, slice_obj.stop, slice_obj.step, kind=self.name
   1798         )

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in slice_indexer(self, start, end, step, kind)
   4711         slice(1, 3)
   4712         """
-> 4713         start_slice, end_slice = self.slice_locs(start, end, step=step, kind=kind)
   4714 
   4715         # return a slice

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in slice_locs(self, start, end, step, kind)
   4930         end_slice = None
   4931         if end is not None:
-> 4932             end_slice = self.get_slice_bound(end, "right", kind)
   4933         if end_slice is None:
   4934             end_slice = len(self)

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_slice_bound(self, label, side, kind)
   4846             except ValueError:
   4847                 # raise the original KeyError
-> 4848                 raise err
   4849 
   4850         if isinstance(slc, np.ndarray):

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_slice_bound(self, label, side, kind)
   4840         # we need to look up the label
   4841         try:
-> 4842             slc = self.get_loc(label)
   4843         except KeyError as err:
   4844             try:

~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2646                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2647             except KeyError:
-> 2648                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))
   2649         indexer = self.get_indexer([key], method=method, tolerance=tolerance)
   2650         if indexer.ndim > 1 or indexer.size > 1:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: '01/06/20'
```

I thought that the lines referred to datetime should avoid this problem, but it doesn't.

How can I solve it?

Thank you

Comment: Hi, what is the purpose of `csv_doc.loc[:, 'Country/Region': date]`?

Comment: Post a sample of your dataframe and desired output.

Comment: @Laurent: I want to select only some columns. From 'Country/Region' until the one is shown in the selected date

Comment: @AmitVikramSingh: I edited the information, you're right

Comment: @icatalan Add the full error traceback.

Comment: It would have been better to add the traceback before implementing the modifications I suggested in my answer, which I believe solved your problem. Now, the traceback indicates that csv_doc is not a dataframe, because you have a mistake at the beginning of your function, where you assign the result of pd.read_csv to `csv_document` => rename it `csv_doc`.

Comment: @Laurent, thanks. I realized this was wrong. I updated the error shown. The one that is related with the date.

Comment: Thx @icatalan. I recognize now the error message you're getting, it has something to do with columns being not properly sorted. I updated my answer accordingly, have a look.

Comment: Thank you very much @Laurent, now works perfectly! So finally changed the dataframe and the input data, right?

Comment: Sorry @Laurent, One more question. I saved all this data as a pickle.Then ````country_cases = pickle.load(open("primera_ola.pkl", "rb"))
print("The timeseries of Andorra is {}".format(country_cases["Andorra"]))````  An error happens due to the change of the type of columns I guess: ````TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str```` Would you change again the type of the column of 'Country/Region'?

Comment: No, I don't think so. 'country_cases' seems to be a list, no a dataframe (or a dictionary), so you have first to convert it so that country_cases["Andorra"] can be a valid call.

Comment: @Laurent, I converted it into a pickle. When loading the document, it converts to a list. I can't do anything to avoid the conversion, can I?

Comment: Pickle/Unpickle process is supposed to leave the object unchanged, so you're perhaps doing it in a wrong way. As per SO rules https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment, comments should not be used to chat or have secondary discussion. Please consider posting a separate question about your new problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`date.strftime("%m/%d/%y")` returns `01/31/20`, whereas the same column in your dataframe is labelled `1/31/20`, thus the mismatch.

I would suggest that you try this:

```py
def create_covid_pickle (csv_doc, date):
    csv_doc = pd.read_csv(csv_doc)

    # properly format csv_doc columns
    csv_doc.columns = [
    datetime.datetime.strptime(col, "%m/%d/%y").strftime("%m/%d/%y")
    if col.replace("/", "").isnumeric()
    else col
    for col in csv_doc.columns
    ]
    
    # assign correct format to date
    date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date,"%m-%d-%y")
    date = date.strftime("%m/%d/%y")

    # Sort columns
    csv_doc = csv_doc.sort_index(axis=1, ascending=False)
        
    # delete columns I don't need
    csv_doc = csv_doc.loc[:, 'Country/Region': date]
    ...
```

Comment: by changing the format like this, the problem is that there are columns like ````Province/State - Country/Region - Lat Long```` which are not valid for this syntax

Comment: In that case, you can add a condition check, see my updated answer.

Comment: many thanks. I added it. The error remains. ````KeyError: '1-31-20'`````Some errors are shown before. The first one is: ````ValueError    Traceback (most recent call last)
~/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_slice_bound(self, label, side, kind)
   ...````

Comment: Hi @Laurent, The columns at the CSV file are shown in format ````dd/mm/yy````, whereas the input data is given in format ````dd-mm-yy````. My goal is to set correctly the input data value to format ````dd/mm/yy`````to avoid problems.

Comment: I'll re-ask this on the website as I coudn't solve this. I'll try to ask it in another way.